# insert calculated values into two tables with one function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have 2 tables and after insert few columns in first table I need calculate other columns and put aggregated values in second table

for example

```
a|b|c|       d|e|f|
1|5| |
1|5| |
```

I need to insert a and b columns of first table into d and e columns in second table, and c column in first table is value of (b-c).

I have a function like

```
declare
 cursor1 CURSOR FOR
  SELECT SUM(a) as a, SUM(b) as b
begin
 FOR cur_rec in cursor 1
  LOOP
   insert into b(d, e)
   values (cur_rec.a, cur_rec.b)
on conflict etc...
```

how can I insert in first table c column result of (a-b) calculated in this function? all values ~INT

I want result like

```
a|b|c|       d|e|f|
1|5|4|       2|10|8
1|5|4|
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: done, added second set of tables with result

Comment: Why 5 in column `b`?

Comment: random integers just for example

Comment: Do you want a solution in SQL?

Comment: I need to know the solution and how to insert the solution into the procedure, which I described

Comment: How do you get the value for e. It does NOT follow from the code segment you have provided.

Comment: my bad, already fixed

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want two statements:

```
update table1
    set c = b - a;

update table2
    set d = t1.a,
        e = t1.b,
        f = t1.c
    from (select sum(a) as a, sum(b) as b, sum(c) as c
          from table1
         ) t1;
```

Comment: the function that I wrote solves the problem with aggregates, I just need to calculate c in this function